# Wife left without warning - talaq?

Tags: talaq

If a wife leaves without any indication and is unable to get a hold of her, and her behavior/attitude has changed also in this process - how can one give a talaq/divorce her islamically?

Unable to reach her by all means of communication (email, phone, text) and not knowing her family location either to pass on a message.

This is a tough time and very worrying as well. She has indeed put lots of strain on me however, this is not working out and this just takes the last straw.

So how can one give a talaq given this situation?

Comment: Give missing complaint, to best of my knowledge, divorce word is to be communicated by any means in her **pure period**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all FOUR schools of thought a husband can give a talaaq without the wife being present.

Comment: Proof for your claim